# R fatal errors with ape & bayestraits, treefile issues?

Tags: r, error-handling, ape-phylo

I am trying to root my phylogenetic tree in R using the ape package root function.
First, reading in the tree and making it class phylo,

```
pomptree<-"Pomptrees"
PompTree<-ape::read.nexus(pomptree)
```

Then creating my outgroup,

```
Outgroup<-c("Brachycistis_alcanor_U51B22","Brachycistis_curvata_U72B92","Brachycistis_petiolata_U68B68",
"Dasymutilla_blattoserica_U88JP841","Dasymutilla_creon_U87JP670","Dasymutilla_monticola_U85JP371","Dasymutilla_quadrigutatta_U83JP313",
"Invreiella_cephalargia_PS113")
```

Then using the following code to root the tree with this outgroup designated.

```
PompTreeRoot<-root(PompTree,Outgroup,resolve.root = TRUE, edgelabel = TRUE)
```

But, I get the below error and sometimes R experiences a fatal error:

```
Error in x$edge[neworder, ] : invalid subscript type 'any'
```

There are plenty of examples with "invalid subscript type 'line' ", but I cannot find what the 'any' means. I think it is something in my treefile that R is not liking, because I also can't run the R package for bayestraites either without a fatal error and the below error message

```
Error in phy$edge.lenght[-terms] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I get the meaning of this error, but have no clue how to address the issue, or where to even start. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing your actual tree. It could be an issue with your outgroup not being monophyletic.  Have you tried the more forgiving function [`TreeTools::RootTree()`](https://ms609.github.io/TreeTools/reference/RootTree.html) in place of `root()`?

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that FigTree nexus output has some branch lengths as scientific notation, and that was causing a problem in R. I couldn't figure out a way to automatically change all of those, so I just had to do it manually for now.

Comment: That's interesting; it's possibly worth mentioning this at [ape](https://github.com/emmanuelparadis/ape/issues) as it's possible the nexus parser in `read.nexus()` could be improved to support this.